# Teamspeak Framework Documentation Explanation

Tags: php, teamspeak, ts3phpframework

Im using the TS Framework to read out some data through the Teamspeak Query in PHP.
But the documentation is horrible!

To display all IPs from all clients I use this code:

```
foreach($ts3_VirtualServer->clientList() as $client)
{
    // skip query clients
    if($client["client_type"]) continue;

    $clientInfo = $client->getInfo();
    echo $clientInfo['connection_client_ip'] . "<br>";
}
```

(it's not the full code)

Where is the part in the documentation which says what `getInfo()` returns?

[Documentation Link](https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___node___abstract.html#af63ae54f10c02ec6b1033425f795fef4)

Comment: If the documentation doesn't help, use `var_dump($clientInfo)` to see what it contains.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider Okay this is possible for my example. But the function getProperty(property) returns the value of the Property. But i cant find anywhere which Properties are possible for e.g. the virtualServer Variable!? https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___node___abstract.html#a585728537b56194aeab30b0316126b89

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738039/teamspeak-query-number-of-connected-clients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in the documentation since it's abstract / generalized for all node objects.

As you can see from [TeamSpeak3_Node_Abstract::getInfo()](https://docs.planetteamspeak.com/ts3/php/framework/class_team_speak3___node___abstract.html#ac60d6af1acba9d78d719d4b86e987c07):

```
if ($extend) {
  $this->fetchNodeInfo();
}

if ($convert) {
  $info = $this->nodeInfo;

  foreach ($info as $key => $val) {
    $key = TeamSpeak3_Helper_String::factory($key);
    //...
  }

  return $info;
}

return $this->nodeInfo;
```

The data returned (formatted or directly) is `TeamSpeak3_Node_Abstract::$nodeInfo`.

[Searching](https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework/search?l=PHP&q=nodeInfo+%3D+&type=Code) GitHub repo for `nodeInfo =` shows how several of the (child) Nodes set their inherited `nodeInfo` property.

For example, we have [TeamSpeak3_Node_Host::fetchNodeInfo()](https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework/blob/7889a6b6855a7dd9657f119f0d9ed0ea4b9c1c55/libraries/TeamSpeak3/Node/Host.php#L921) which uses properties returned by TeamSpeak3 Server Query commands `hostinfo`, `instanceinfo`:

```
protected function fetchNodeInfo() {
  $info1          = $this->request("hostinfo")->toList();
  $info2          = $this->request("instanceinfo")->toList();
  $this->nodeInfo = array_merge($this->nodeInfo, $info1, $info2);
}
```

Also, for example, [TeamSpeak3_Node_Server::fetchNodeInfo()](https://github.com/planetteamspeak/ts3phpframework/blob/6ec52131e7be9913439e4c3913fcc356294b6c84/libraries/TeamSpeak3/Node/Server.php#L2406) which uses properties returned by `serverinfo` command:

```
protected function fetchNodeInfo() {
  $this->nodeInfo = array_merge($this->nodeInfo,
    $this->request("serverinfo")->toList());
}
```

As you can imagine, several TeamSpeak3 objects have a corresponding `*info` command which returns that object's properties.

You can view several example results of these commands, along with properties returned, in the TeamSpeak3 Server Query manual. Here for example, the [serverinfo](http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Query%20Manual.pdf#page=11) command.

Also, at the end of the manual, you can find several list of object properties.
For example, the [virtual server properties](http://media.teamspeak.com/ts3_literature/TeamSpeak%203%20Server%20Query%20Manual.pdf#page=41).